# How can I get the SUM of 'costs' for every year + all the years before it?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables called `wh_time` and `wh_fact` where `wh_time` include both columns `time_id` and `year_id`, and `wh_fact` include both columns `time_id` and `cost`.
I try to use rollup function to get the sum of costs for every year with the costs of the years before it .. for example:

- year 2000 with cost 500,
- year 2001 with cost 400,
- year 2002 with cost 300,
- year 2003 with cost 100

for the year 2002, I want (cost for 2002 = the sum of costs for all 2000, 2001 and 2002)

I try this, but it doesnt work .. any help!

```
SELECT year_id, SUM(cost) 
      FROM wh_fact f
      INNER JOIN wh_time t ON t.time_id = f.time_id  
GROUP BY ROLLUP (year_id, cost)
ORDER BY year_id
;
```

Comment: Can you share the DDLs to define your table? Or better yet, an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: I dont get the results I want .... 
In the example above:
the result should be:
year_id  = 2000 >> cost = 500 , 
year_id = 2001 >> cost = 900 , 
year_id = 2002 >> cost = 1200 , 
year_id = 2003 >> cost = 1300 , 
and sorry if am not good at explain..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytic functions to do what is essentially a running sum:

```
select year_id,
       sum_cost as cost_this_yr,
       sum(sum_cost) over( order by year_id
                           rows between unbounded preceding
                            and current row ) as run_sum
  from (select year_id, sum(cost) as sum_cost
          from wh_fact
          join wh_time
         using (time_id)
         group by year_id)
 order by year_id
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0f27/3/0

```
| YEAR_ID | COST_THIS_YR | RUN_SUM |
|---------|--------------|---------|
|    2000 |          500 |     500 |
|    2001 |          400 |     900 |
|    2002 |          300 |    1200 |
|    2003 |          100 |    1300 |
```

(if you don't want the cost_this_yr column, just remove it from the select list)